# Autofac WCF environment issue - The AutofacServiceHost.Container static property must be set before services can be instantiated

Tags: wcf, autofac, svc

We're seeing this error in a customer environment with our WCF services.

We haven't been able to reproduce in house with the same Dlls and web.config settings. Therefore, I'm assuming it's an issue with the environment.

Any suggestions for things to check on the server?

This is the error we're seeing when browsing to any of the .svc files:

> [InvalidOperationException: The AutofacServiceHost.Container static
>   property must be set before services can be instantiated.]
>   Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String
>   constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +478
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1429
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo
>   serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +52
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +598

Comment: can you post your global.asax file and your web.config ?

Comment: At some times global.asax is not working. It may be a misconfiguration of IIS as well. Just as a safer precaution it makes sense puting init code into static constructor of `MyHostFactory : AutofacHostFactory`

Answer (score 1):

Solved.  The customer environment was missing the global.asax file.  :(